# How can I add a method for ordering an array plus a method to reverse the order of the array?

Tags: java, arrays

The question I was given is asking me to write a `orderedArray` method as well as a `reverseArray` method.

I have done this but I used a static void which makes only the first written method to work and the following method to not work. The ordering method works but not the reverse order method.

If I delete one of the methods it works, no matter which I delete the other work, if that makes sense.

This is the code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args)
    {       
        int[] orderedArray = {1,4,3,2,5};
        Arrays.sort(orderedArray);
        for(int num : orderedArray) {
            System.out.print(num + " ");
        }
    }
    
    public static void main1(String[] args) {
        
        int[] reverseArray = {1,2,3,4,5};
        for(int i=reverseArray.length-1;i>=0;i--)
            System.out.print(reverseArray[i] + "  ");
    }
```

I am just wondering if there is a better way to write this or how I can make it two separate methods so they work at the same time rather than the scenario I currently have.

If anyone has any suggestions I would greatly appreciate it

Comment: You can have as many methods in your java programs as you want. You just need to call them for them to be executed. The `public static void main` method is just the entry point of your program, but there is nothing stopping you from calling as many other methods from that entry point as you want. I recommend reading a beginners tutorial that deals with how you define and call methods in java.

Comment: If you were asked to write "orderedArray" and "reverseArray" methods, why did you name them instead "main" and "main1" ?

Answer (score 1):

the ordering method works because it is inside main method.
In java the first method run is the main method, instead the reverse method is inside another method and you never call it, that is the reason why only ordering method works.

You could create:
a main method, two different method and call them inside your main.
Like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] array = {1,4,3,2,5};
    orderedArray(array);
    System.out.println("");
    reverseArray(array);
}

public static void reverseArray(Integer[] args) {
    Arrays.sort(args,Collections.reverseOrder());
    System.out.print("reverse array ");
    for(int i:args)
    {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
}
public static void orderedArray(Integer[] args) {
    Arrays.sort(args);
    System.out.print("ordered array ");
    for(int num : args) {
        System.out.print(num + " ");
    }
}
```

The result will be

ordered array 1 2 3 4 5

reverse array 5 4 3 2 1